# How efficient is Qiskit's unitary decomposition?

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-gate, unitarity, universal-gates

In Qiskit's extension package we have the `UnitaryGate` module that you can initialize using a unitary matrix and then add it to your circuit. How efficiently is this decomposition done under the hood?

Also, if I wanted to do the decomposition myself, what's the best way of doing so?

Comment: Some basic information might be useful: Nielsen's chap 4(the part of general gates), and Solovay-Kitaev's algorithm. There is also some reinforce-learning way for gate decomposition, such as [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.04743). While I am also curious about the complexity lower bound of the problem.

Comment: @narip Solovay-Kitaev is largely irrelevant here. There, you're trying to decompose a gate from a finite gate set. In Qiskit, the rotations have a continuous parameter available to them.

Comment: @DaftWullie But does the problem mean that UnitaryGate(A) can add any unitary matrix $A$ into the circuit? So with the help of the UnitaryGate() function, we may have any unitary matrix at hand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For 2x2 unitary, it is just a [U3-gate](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.U3Gate.html).

For 4x4 unitary, [`TwoQubitBasisDecomposer`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.TwoQubitBasisDecomposer.html) is used. `TwoQubitBasisDecomposer` implements KAK decomposition method described in [arXiv:0806.4015](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.4015) by Drury and Love. This method uses optimal number of CNOT gates.

For larger unitaries, [`Isometry`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/extensions/quantum_initializer/isometry.html) class is used. This class implements the method introduced by Iten et al. in [arXiv:1501.06911](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.06911). This method achieves the theoretical lower bound on the number of used CNOT gates.

---

**Update**: In Qiskit version 0.37 a new module `qiskit.quantum_info.synthesis.qsd` is added to apply Quantum Shannon Decomposition of arbitrary unitaries. This functionality replaces the previous isometry-based approach.

The Quantum Shannon Decomposition ([arXiv:quant-ph/0406176](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0406176)) uses about half the CNOT gates as the isometry implementation when decomposing unitary matrices of greater than two qubits.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! Do you think there is a detailed overview of the Qiskit comilation/transpilation process somewhere? Here is one https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/transpiler.html but it is quite brief. Currently the bits and pieces that I pick from scattered posts on QC.SE are my main sources.

Comment: Glad to help. My main source is the code, including this answer.

Comment: Do you know which method the Isometry class in Qiskit uses? The cited paper by Iten et al. presents 3 methods: Knill, Column-by-column (CCD), Cosine-Sine (CSD). By the source code it looks to me like they use CCD, but I am not sure.