# How exactly does the QuantumCircuit.decompose() method work?

Tags: programming, qiskit, gate-synthesis

From what I can understand from the [source code](https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/transpiler/passes/basis/decompose.html), the circuit is converted into a DAG before the decomposition transpiler is performed onto the DAG circuit.

How does converting to a DAG circuit help us recognise the gate operations needed to reach a certain state say for example the entangled state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle +|11\rangle)$. Or basically, how does that decomposition work?

Comment: [This](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/18160/16092) answer may help giving you an idea