# Brute force gate decomposition of (specific) 4 qubit unitary matrix

Tags: gate-synthesis

I have a specific 4-qubit `16x16` unitary matrix $U$ with $9$ parameters. My goal is to find a gate decomposition in terms of e.g. `{Rx, Ry, Rz, CNOT}`. I feel like there must be a brute force way to find that, but the parametrization is making it non-trivial. Would appreciate any pointers, input or help regarding that :-)

Thank you in advance!
Kind regards,
Korbinian

Comment: Why are you not using qiskit or similar libraries to do this? https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28424/qiskit-can-you-get-circuit-from-unitary-matrix?rq=1

Comment: Its a numeric 16x16 matrix right? Symbolic unitary synthesis is a harder problem. Wasnt entirely sure what you meant when you said 9 parameters.

Comment: Can you give your concrete matrix?

Comment: I'm looking for a brute - force algorithm to find _a_ decomposition for a _specific_ 4-qubit unitary matrix. The matrix is parameterized, which makes the problem a bit harder, that is why I mentioned it.

Comment: So can you write your unitary out? Such as $\left( \begin{matrix}
 \cos \theta&  -\sin \theta\\
 \sin \theta&  \cos \theta\\
\end{matrix} \right) $?

Comment: Yes, there is an explicit form of the 16x16 matrix in terms of cos sin etc.

Comment: So, can you write it in your post?

Comment: This is called unitary synthesis, and the BQSKit package can do this using one of its synthesis algorithms. If you want a tool to do it, try bqskit. If you are curious on how this is done, you can check out ths qsearch, leap, or qfast papers reference on bqskit's website: bqskit.lbl.gov